# vim commandの複数実行について

Tags: vim

複数の正規表現をvim commandを利用して実行をしたいと考えています。

```
command Check :%s/hogehoge//g|:%s/fugafuga//g
```

一つ目のhogehogeが見つからない場合、「パターンは見つかりませんでした。」で処理が止まり、
fugafugaのマッチングは行われないようです。

vim commandをパイプで繋ぎ、複数実行するとエラー時に処理が中断されるようです。
これを無視、あるいは回避する方法ありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:s` の最後のフラグに e を付けると、マッチ対象が見つからなかった場合にもエラーが出なくなります。

```
command Check %s/hogehoge//ge | %s/fugafuga//ge
```

Comment: こちら、commandを実行したところ意図通りに動作しました。
vim commadで考えすぎてました、ありがとうございます。